# Checkbox for outdoor brightness in Samsung Galaxy S7 running Android 7

Tags: android, screen, samsung-mobile, samsung-galaxy

I had a Samsung Galaxy J7. It was great when I walk outdoor because the brightness can be adjusted marking a checkbox in the notifications bar

[image]

Recently I switched for a Galaxy S7, unfortunately, this phone doesn't have this checkbox. There is a way to activate the chekbox in the galaxy S7???

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this question belongs here.
With that being said, check Settings -> Display, you should have an option called "Auto adjust brightness'. Even simpler, you can click the down arrow on the right of the brightness slide and it will show the same option.